# Redux: Strange destructuring syntax inside the Redux docs example's connect method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been checking out the [redux github examples](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/64a8c66b454163660f9d49bcce92a3230cdbcb2a/examples/shopping-cart/containers/ProductsContainer.js) and I'm a little tripped up by the weird syntax used export an action like add `addToCart`.

First `addToCart` is imported using es6 importing and then the confusing part is how it is then accessed with destructuring to pass to the `connect` function.

Like index.js shows, `addToCart` is a function that creates a closure and returns a function. So I don't get how destructuring is being used instead of `addToCart()`.

I tried replicating but I get an error that the action should return a plain object.

**Question:**

Could someone explain what the desturcturing syntax is doing here?

**ProductsContainer.js**

```
import { addToCart } from '../actions';

...

class ProductsContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    const { products } = this.props
    return (
      <ProductsList title="Products">
        {products.map(product =>
          <ProductItem
            key={product.id}
            product={product}
            onAddToCartClicked={() => this.props.addToCart(product.id)} />
        )}
      </ProductsList>
    )
  }
}

...

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { addToCart }
)(ProductsContainer)
```

**index.js**

```
export function addToCart(productId) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (getState().products.byId[productId].inventory > 0) {
      dispatch(addToCartUnsafe(productId))
    }
  }
}

function addToCartUnsafe(productId) {
  return {
    type: types.ADD_TO_CART,
    productId
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a peek here for some background:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

But that's happening here is that the second argument of the `react-redux`'s `connect` function take an object (or function). And in the case of the object, the keys are mapped to functions - so we're actually just creating a new object, that has a key of `addToCart`, which references the `addToCart` action function, which you imported:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { addToCart: addToCart }
)(ProductsContainer)
```

**Update**: The `addToCart` import is actually a thunk (which is a function that wraps an expression to delay its evaluation (see https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#whats-a-thunk) As such, it appears that `react-redux` is able to invoke these thunks in a way that the object they create (i.e. `redux` actions), are appropriately passed to the `dispatcher`.

Comment: Im not getting at what point are we getting the inner closure. Im use to the idea that you have to call the wrapper first ```var closure = addToCart()```  and what it returns then would be the function to add to the dispatchToProps ```{addToCart:closure}```

Comment: We're basically just passing the callback to the connect function.  But hmm, not sure what you mean by "getting the inner closure"

Comment: The ```addToCart``` is a function that returns a function. So it should be imported and then called in order to create the callback that the connect is using. Or so i would think.

Comment: Yes, addToCart is a thunk, and mapDispatchToProps really looks like this: `const mapDispatchToProp = ({dispatch}) => { return { addToCart: (item) => dispatch(addToCart(item)}}` Not sure if this clarifies.

Comment: where the last `addToCart` is where your action creator is actually getting invoked to generate the new action obj.

Comment: Ohhhh So I guess it what is confusing the crap out of me is this "thunk" thing I know nada about. Throw that in the answer so I can accept it. Thx a lot @lux

Comment: No problem at all, hopefully the update clears things up. Also FWIW, here's my VERY small boilerplate project for React, which has some really decent jumping off point for Redux: https://github.com/mikechabot/react-boilerplate

Comment: Oh it looks sweeeeet I starred it!

Answer (score 0):

The { addToCart } in the connect call is es6 shorthand for { addToCart: addToCart }. So it is passing an object to connect that contains a single method called addToCart. Or if you prefer obj.addToCart().

The { Foo } syntax in es6 is confusing as it is used for two different things.

```
const bar "bar";
const foo = { bar };
```

Gives foo.bar === "bar', where as,

```
const foo = { bar: "bar" };
const { bar } = foo;
```

Gives bar === "bar".